# Numerical problem with error function

Tags: numerics

```
theta=.1;
ep=150;
w2= .1;
c=1/2;
rho[t_]:=1+ c Sin[w2 t ];
h=0.25;
S=ep (1+ c Sin[w2 t ]);
x=0.2;
Plot[{ (E^(2 h S x+S x^2-2 h S x^2) theta (Erfi[((-1+h) Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1+2 h]]- 
 Erfi[(Sqrt[S] (-h-x+2 h x))/Sqrt[-1+2 h]]))/((Erfi[((-1+h) Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1+2 
h]]+Erfi[(h Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1+2 h]]) x (1-x)) },{t,100,300},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle-> 
{{Red, Dashed}, Blue}]
```

It gives me the numerical problem, I know that the function is a smooth function which is obtained for small ep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Use exact values for known constants and add the option [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) to the plot.

```
theta = 1/10;
ep = 150;
w2 = 1/10;
c = 1/2;
rho[t_] := 1 + c Sin[w2 t];
h = 1/4;
S = ep (1 + c Sin[w2 t]);
x = 1/5;

Plot[{(E^(2 h S x + S x^2 - 
        2 h S x^2) theta (Erfi[((-1 + h) Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]] - 
       Erfi[(Sqrt[S] (-h - x + 2 h x))/
         Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]]))/((Erfi[((-1 + h) Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]] + 
       Erfi[(h Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]]) x (1 - x))}, {t, 100, 300}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, Blue},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just add `WorkingPrecision->5`  in your `Plot`command

```
Plot[{(E^(2 h S x + S x^2 - 
         2 h S x^2) theta (Erfi[((-1 + h) Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]] - 
        Erfi[(Sqrt[S] (-h - x + 2 h x))/
          Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]]))/((Erfi[((-1 + h) Sqrt[S])/
          Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]] + Erfi[(h Sqrt[S])/Sqrt[-1 + 2 h]]) x (1 - 
        x))}, {t, 100, 300}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, Blue}, WorkingPrecision -> 5] // Quiet
```

[image]